# c++ changing rgba cube to have one color on each side

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-studio-2012, cube

I've been slowly learning how to work with 3d graphics and C++ and I've been working with an RGBA using an example from Ed angels interactive computer graphics. When trying to change it to have a color on each side, I hit a wall in either my understanding or I'm not seeing something obvious. A snippet of the original example I used that created a RGBA cube is this:

```
const int NumVertices = 36;

point4 points[NumVertices];
color4 colors[NumVertices];

//Vertices of a unit cube centered at origin, sides aligned with axes
point4 vertices[8] = {
    point4( -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0),
    point4( -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0),
    point4( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0),
    point4( 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0),
    point4( -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0),
    point4( -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0),
    point4( 1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0),
    point4( 1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0)
};

//RGBA colors
color4 vertex_colors[8] = {
    color4( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0),  //black
    color4( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0),  //red
    color4( 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0),  //yellow
    color4( 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0),  //blue
    color4( 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0),  //green
    color4( 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0),  //magenta
    color4( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0),  //white
    color4( 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)  //cyan
};

//Array of rotation angles (in degrees) for each coordinate axis
enum { Xaxis = 0, Yaxis = 1, Zaxis = 2, NumAxes = 3 };
int Axis = Xaxis;
GLfloat Theta[NumAxes] = { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0};

GLuint theta; //The location of the "theta" shader uniform variable
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

//quad generates two triangles for each face and assigns colors to the vertices

int Index = 0;
void
quad( int a, int b, int c, int d)
{
    colors[Index] = vertex_colors[a]; points[Index] = vertices[a]; Index++;
    colors[Index] = vertex_colors[b]; points[Index] = vertices[b]; Index++;
    colors[Index] = vertex_colors[c]; points[Index] = vertices[c]; Index++;
    colors[Index] = vertex_colors[a]; points[Index] = vertices[a]; Index++;
    colors[Index] = vertex_colors[c]; points[Index] = vertices[c]; Index++;
    colors[Index] = vertex_colors[d]; points[Index] = vertices[d]; Index++;
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

//generate 12 triangles: 36 vertices and 36 colors
void
colorcube( void )
{
    quad( 1, 0, 3, 2);
    quad( 2, 3, 7, 6);
    quad( 3, 0, 4, 7);
    quad( 6, 5, 1, 2);
    quad( 4, 5, 6, 7);
    quad( 5, 4, 0, 1);
}
```

Now all i thought I had to do from what I read was just change the all the parameters of vertex_colors in *quad* to *a* making them all the same like this:

```
int Index = 0;
void
quad( int a, int b, int c, int d)
{
    colors[Index] = vertex_colors[a]; points[Index] = vertices[a]; Index++;
    colors[Index] = vertex_colors[a]; points[Index] = vertices[b]; Index++;
    colors[Index] = vertex_colors[a]; points[Index] = vertices[c]; Index++;
    colors[Index] = vertex_colors[a]; points[Index] = vertices[a]; Index++;
    colors[Index] = vertex_colors[a]; points[Index] = vertices[c]; Index++;
    colors[Index] = vertex_colors[a]; points[Index] = vertices[d]; Index++;
}
```

But when I did this all the was generated was a blank white window. So what I'm confused on is there more then just changing the parameters or do I need to work with something else to get it working?

Comment: Just to triple check, you can rotate to see all faces so it's not just that the white face is the only visible one?

Comment: Yeah when I run it and try to rotate it it still stays all white. I don't feel like its the fact that there's only 6 or then it wouldn't run when I don't alter the parameters of vertex_colors.